# Keyboard shortcut for radio buttons vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to select radio button using keyboard?

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.KeyDown
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.S) Then
            RadioButton2.Checked = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what is your error ?

Answer (score -1):

This is not understandable that why are you using **KeyDown** event of a RadioButton to access its functionality by pressing short-cut key like 'ALt + R'.

Use an **&** character to assign the access key before your desire alphabet at its Text Property ,as you do for other controls.